# How to handle 400 Bad request with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I'd like to send parameters via ajax post request but I always get status 400. Here's the js

```
$(document).on('click','#create-chart-button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fields = {};
    $('.can-drop').each(function(item){
        fields[item] = ($(this)[0].innerText);
    }) ; 
    console.log(fields);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/create/api/',
        data: {     
            "fields": fields,
        },
        cache: true,


    success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
     }

   })
});
```

Data are taken from a draggable object chosen by the user. This is an example of parameters I get in the request object:

```
fields[0]:"name"
fields[1]:"jobtime"
fields[2]:"id"
```

I'm using flask and this is my route:

```
@app.route('/create/api/', methods=['POST'])
def populate_chart():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fields = request.form['fields']
        print(fields) 
        pass
```

I'd like not to use a form. While debugging, ajax data are in request.form (even if I'm not using the form). But then I've got the same error. 
I've tried to use JSON.stringfy but nothing seems to change.
I'll continue to try solutions, but this error comes to me everytime I use ajax and post so I'd like to understand where the error is to fix it. Thanks!

UPDATE
While debugging I saw this:

```
    def __getitem__(self, key):
    """Return the first data value for this key;
    raises KeyError if not found.

    :param key: The key to be looked up.
    :raise KeyError: if the key does not exist.
    """
    if key in self:
        lst = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        if len(lst) > 0:
            return lst[0]
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
```

And my data are:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('fields[0]', 'callid'), ('fields[1]', 'jobtime')])
```

The exception is raised because the key il "fields" but there is no key in the data passed that match "fields". So I'm going to pass data in a different way (I guess)...